# Is x86 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a copy of Windows in MSDNAA and it says Windows Vista x86. Is this Windows Vista 32 bit, or 64 bit?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In current terminology `x86` normally indicates 32-bits, with `x86-64` or `x64` indicating 64-bits.

[`x86`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) really refers to an **instruction set** based on the Intel 8086 (from some time ago - 1973 by Wikipedia's reckoning). Nowadays this normally is taken to simply mean a 32-bit instruction set. Initally it was a set of instructions that operated with only 16-bit, so historically could be referred to as `x86-16` or `x86-32`. But, obviously, `x86-16` is no longer relevant as 16-bit processors died out a long time ago.

[`x86-64`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) (or just `x64`) is an *extension* to the `x86` instruction set, providing support for 64-bit registers, memory space and the like. It is fully backwards compatible with the 32-bit `x86` instruction set (allowing 32-bit software to be compatabile without modification *in most cases*) and is taken to simply mean a 64-bit instruction set.

There are vendor-specific names for `x86-64` as well - it can be referred to  `AMD64` or `Intel 64` (previous `IA-32e` and `EM64T`).

Answer (score 13):

Windows Vista reports `x86` for 32bit version and `x86-64` for 64bit version.

Answer (score 7):

it's a 32 Bit version of Windows

Answer (score 4):

- **You have a 32 bit Version**
- **x86** is for **32 bit only**. It is sometimes also referred to as **x86- 32** .
- **x86- 64** supports **64 bit**. They often referred by the term **x64**

Comment: The last part of your answer doesn't make sense. x86 refers to 32-bit, so you *can* be sure.

Comment: I am sorry there was some editing mistake in my answer, hence it seemed to be a wrong answer